# Send value of selected radio button to ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<select onChange="getclass(this.value); name="Course_ID" >
```

I have an ajax function 'getclass' which gets called whenever i change the value of my dropdown list.
I want to pass the value of a radio button as well to the ajax function whenever this function gets called.

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="c" checked="checked"> Class<br>
```

Here is the ajax function

```
function getclass(val1) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_class.php",
        data:'id='+val1,
        success: function(data){
        $("#class-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to pass the value of a radio button as well to the ajax function whenever this function gets called. -> ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass radio button value to a variable and use in ajax:

```
function getclass(val1) {
    var radVal = $("input[type=radio][name=type]:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_class.php",
        data: { 'id': val1, 'radVal': radVal },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#class-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```